# How to send GET request to Web-Api using Angularjs and PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I am new in Angularjs and PhoneGap. I am trying to send a get request to my Web-Api 2 project using Angularjs and PhoneGap but i getting an error. It is working in each browser.

My Code is :

```
taxiConceptControllers.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'loginService', '$http',
 function ($scope, $routeParams, loginService, $http) {
  $scope.loginProvider = loginService.url;
  $scope.intLoginProvider = function () {
      console.log("call");
      $http({
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
          method: "GET",
          url: 'http://localhost:15229/api/values',
      }).success(function (userData) {
          console.log(userData);
      }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('error');
      });
  };
}]);
```

Error :

[image]

My web-Api 2 support Cross.

it will return JSON format result and it will be `["value1","value2"]` but i get an error.

I am using :

- Visual Studio 2013 ultimate with windows Phone 8 SDK
- Angularjs 1.2.14
- PhoneGap 2.9.1

**Update 1 :**

I put those lines :

```
     console.log(status);
     console.log(headers);
     console.log(config);
```

Output is :

```
     404
      function(c){a||(a=nc(b));return c?a[O(c)]||null:a}
[object Object]
```

**Update 2 :** [image]

More about my error.

**Update 3 :**

my Index.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="taxiConceptApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Hello World</title>


    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="contnr" ng-view>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>



    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="js/service/appservice.js"></script>
    <script src="js/service/loginservice.js"></script>

    <script src="js/controllers/loginctrl.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My App.js is :

```
var taxiConceptControllers = angular.module('taxiConceptControllers', []);

var taxiConceptApp = angular.module('taxiConceptApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'taxiConceptControllers'
]);

var onDeviceReady = function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['taxiConceptApp']);
};
document.addEventListener('deviceready',
onDeviceReady);

taxiConceptApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/Login', {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        }).
        when('/phones/:phoneId', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
            controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/Login'
        });
  }]);
```

Login.Html is :

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl" ng-init="intLoginProvider()">
    <h1>asdasads</h1>
    {{loginProvider}}
</div>
```

My solution Explorer is:

[image]

I use PhoneGap 2.9.1 and build it for windows phone 8

Comment: Could you please post the error message?

Comment: perhaps try using Fiddler

Comment: @Atropo I update Error Messages.

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 Fiddler does not catch anything.

Comment: Do you have `access-origin` configured in the `config.xml`?

Comment: 404 suggests that the url is not correct: http://localhost:15229/api/values try this in your browser and see what you get

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 url is correct. I tested it chrome and IE and it`s return correct result.

Comment: From the picture you've posted seems there's a previous error, like "Cannot find or open the P.. file". Could you please post all the error lines?

Comment: the PDB file - this is for debugging

Comment: @Atropo There no previous error and I does not get any other information about this error.

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 I did not get you.

Comment: The error in the screenshot is "Cannot find or open the PDB file"

Comment: there is also a "System.NotSupportException" occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 I update my Error Messages and please tell me how can i solve this

Comment: you need to post more info, like how you have configured your js code.  from the error, it looks like the code is hosted in Windows Phone? and it is getting a 404 when trying to contact your api.  My guess would be the problem is somewhere in the client

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 I post more info about my project (almost full). Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configured the `config.xml` file to whitelist your domain? Here there's the documentation on the  [access tag](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements) for the [config.xml](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_index.md.html)

Comment: In my config.xml :access tag is <access origin="*" />

Comment: according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559188/phonegap-angularjs-app-restangular-404-always you need to configure a domain whitelist